# Modifying item in viewstate - is it safe to do?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I'm still a relative noob, however I was surprised at the results of a small test I did.

I want to store a list of string in viewstate. To date when I want to modify the list I retrieved it from viewstate, performed a List.Add and saved it back to viewstate.

However, I then decided to do a simple test, here it is below:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<string> s = new List<string>();
            s.Add("abc");
            s.Add("def");
            ViewState.Add("test", s);

            s.Add("one");
            s.Add("two");
        }
        var t = (List<string>)ViewState["test"];

        foreach (var str in t)
        {
            Response.Write(str + "<br>");
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I create a list, add it to viewstate, then modify the list. To my suprise the list is modified in viewstate , even after postback.

The question is, is it safe to do this, and if so is it considered bad practice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of subjective, but I don't see anything wrong with this by practice. This is something that happens all the time within different form controls on the page. The controls will edit viewstate information pertaining to themselves and persist that over postback. The reason the list changes in the viewstate when you modify it after adding it to the viewstate is that it doesn't get immediately serialized. The list is passed by reference to the viewstate collection where it sits until the page serializes the viewstate shortly before completing the request.

Comment: Very informative - now I understand why this is happening, and can therefore determine when its acceptable and not acceptable to use this way.

Comment: There are some serious consequences to storing data in viewstate though, so I don't think its accurate to say "there's nothing wrong with this."  Control state is one thing, since the user can pretty much change the control state directly anyway, but arbitrary data is another.

Comment: @dotnetnoob Please be aware that there can be some negative consequences to storing data in ViewState; its not always safe or a good idea as this answer states.

Answer (score 1):

ViewState is only serialized to the client page at the time of postback.
Previous to that, it is held in memory and safe for editing.

I often use ViewState as a backer to a property:

```
public Class1 MyClass1
{
    get { return (Class1)ViewState["MyClass1"]; }
    set { ViewState["MyClass1"] = value; }
}
```

In general, I would not consider it bad practice to do so, except for the following:

1. Storing sensitive data - Since data is serialized to the client, it is susceptible to being changed.
2. Large amounts of data - Since the data is persisted to the client, it will increase the page load times significantly for large amounts.

Comment: I actually would consider it bad practice; unless you take other steps, view state can be tampered with, which could lead to security issues.  Also, the more you send there, the more data you send back in the response, increasing load time of your page.

Comment: @Andy You're absolutely right about large amounts of data or sensitive data.  However, it seems the question is more specific to editing viewstate data rather than what type of data is ok to store there.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing this is due to the Asp.Net WebForms [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  At the point you're modifying the view state, Asp.Net has not yet rendered the page output as HTML.  Since you're adding a reference to a dictionary, and changes you make prior to rending will show up.  There are other points in the life cycle where such changes might not show up, although I've not investigated to see if that's the case or not.

I would not consider this good practice however.  ViewState is serialized as a hidden form field in your web page, and thus any data in it is part of your page.  This can at best just increase the size of the response sent to the client (sometimes significantly, if you store a lot of data there).  Since it's a hidden form field, the request back to the server is also larger.

It can also open up security holes.  You cannot trust necessarly trust view state, although there are ways you can [secure it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I would say its better not to send any data at all you don't absolutely need to render the page.

As an alternative, you may consider storing state that is specific to the user in [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), although you do need to take some extra effort if you're application will be behind a load balancer in a web farm.  Storing the data in session will keep it isolated from other users and won't require exposing the data at all to the client.